# OpenFL/HTML5 Applying shader to bitmap

Tags: html5-canvas, haxe, openfl

I'm trying to apply a shader to a Bitmap as it's described on this [link](http://www.openfl.org/blog/2016/10/11/custom-shaders-audiosource-and-more-openfl-4-3-and-lime-3-3-released/).

This is the code:

```
var shader = new Shader ();
shader.glFragmentSource = "..."; <- this part is not important

shader.data.useAlphaImage = [ true ];
shader.data.uAlphaImage.input = alphaBitmapData;

bitmap.filters = [ new ShaderFilter (shader) ];
```

But if I apply the shader it gets transparent, with no errors. Do I have to configure something to get it working?

I am targeting HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShaderFilter` is partially disabled in current OpenFL releases. The initial implementation was too slow to work on mobile; there are plans to revisit the feature again written in a different way.

In the meantime, there is a beta API you could try:

```
bitmap.shader = shader;
```

Also, be aware OpenFL uses *premultiplied alpha*, so bear that in mind within your shader when it comes to alpha values. This should be represented in the default shader code.

Comment: Thanks! That works :D ... Is there any place where I can find info about this kind of things? I don't find the openfl documentation really useful

Comment: Until the documentation gets updated, just asking (and looking on the forums) is your best bet